# dell lap control display(lid) close option

Tags: suspend, dell, power-management, laptop, lid

i am using dell lap with Ubuntu 18.04  when the lid (display) close its go  sleep automatic but i need nothing happen

in windows we can control

[HOW TO CHANGE WHAT CLOSING THE LAPTOP LID DOES](https://www.dummies.com/computers/pcs/how-to-change-what-closing-the-laptop-lid-does/)

same like Ubuntu how to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's easy ...

1. `sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf`
2. change the `HandleLidSwitch=suspense` to `HandleLidSwitch=suspense`
   and don't forget to delete the ' # '
3. `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind`

Comment: thz dude its work :D